# Can not connect to tomcat server externally,

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, tomcat, fedora, virtualbox

My Tomcat server is running on virtual server, this server is running on fedora machine. I have setted up everything on this machine to run tomcat, tomcat working well on local host. but i can not access the wsdl of the webservice running on this tomcat server remotely using IP address of this server, as follows.

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/axis2/services/listServices

one of my friend said that i need to configure DNS to access remotely using IP address, i didn't understand what he said also. iptables on this server is also stooped. Also , i can access mysql running on this server remotly, my problem is why doesn't it work for tomcat.

could someone can help me to find a solution for this problem. 
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Is there a chance that the IP address you have your tomcat server bound to is 127.0.0.1?  That's the loopback interface, and is only reachable by the local machine, so it is not remotely accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a host filter: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html

Have you got log entries/server.xml from your Tomcat service? (use pastebin.com)

You certainly don't need DNS if you are using the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You test from the fedora machine to the virtual server?

In the virtual server:

```
netstat -na | grep 8080
```

In the fedora machine:

```
nmap xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```