# tomcat server can not be accesed remotly

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, java, web-services

I am running tomcat server on Fedora machine.

when I run tomcat using following command,

service tomcat start

it runs on localhost ,

but when i try to connect to the server using public ip address of the server as follows remotly

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080

it does not start

could someone help me with this issue

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not connect to tomcat server externally, ](http://serverfault.com/questions/148437/can-not-connect-to-tomcat-server-externally)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the IP address you have your tomcat server bound to is 127.0.0.1, which is the loopback interface only available to the local machine.  Hence it is not available to remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

do:
  netstat -an | grep 8080

What is the output you get?

Also, What is the IP address of that machine and if you are connecting to it remotely, is firewall a factor? Are both boxes are on local n/w to one another? Also, can you do the following from the remote machine while tomcat is running:

telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 8080

What do you get? Thanks